# Subscribe button working in preview, but not on site--Possible Javascript Error(s)?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Simple Wordpress question here:

I'm using a widget to manage my email subscriptions:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><label>Subscribe to Emails</label>
<input style="width: 325px;" name="FNAME" required="" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><input style="width: 325px;" name="EMAIL" required="" type="email" placeholder="Your email address" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></p>
```

When I click ‘Preview This Form’, i’m successfully able to test this with emails. However, when I copy/paste this into my website, the subscribe button does not do anything. It keeps the user on the page with no action.

This form was on all pages of my website. I’ve been doing some additional reading and there may potentially be javascript errors on the page since the form is there multiple times. I removed the form on all pages except for the homepage for now.

The error still occurs. Nothing happens upon clicking submit. Not sure if this is related?

Comment: Have you checked your brower's developer console for javascript errors?  Additionally, this form doesn't have any form tags - which makes it *not* a form....

Comment: Thanks, Caleb!

Yup, just checked the console and no errors there.

Isn't the fact that it's a successfully installed widget in wordpress mean that it's a 'Form' ?  I'm not seeing any form tags in the HTML that they provided me.